# QSortFilterProxyModel does not update the QTableview

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am trying to use QSortFilterProxyModel with QStandardItemmodel but filterAcceptedRows() is not updating the view.

The rows are correctly filetred in the function filterAcceptedRows() but the view is not updated. It is still displaying all the rows. Below you can find the code that i have already tried, could anybody tell me am i missing something here

This is the code in the QDialog.

```
m_modelApp = new QStandardItemModel();
m_proxyApp = new ProxyModelApp();
m_proxyApp->setSourceModel(m_modelApp);
m_lstApp->setModel(m_modelApp);
```

This is how i add data to the model.

```
    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem *item3 = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem *item4 = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem *item5 = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem *itemCheck = new QStandardItem();

    item1->setData(l_sRefProduitSW,Qt::DisplayRole);
    item2->setData("To Define",Qt::DisplayRole);
    item3->setData(app.GetRefApp(),Qt::DisplayRole);
    item4->setData(app.GetRefIdentApp(),Qt::DisplayRole);
    item5->setData(app.GetRefFNRApp(),Qt::DisplayRole);

    itemCheck->setCheckable(true);
    if(m_xRefBe->GetListeAppBE().contains(app))
        itemCheck->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
    else
        itemCheck->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);

    listItems<<itemCheck<<item1<<item2<<item3<<item4<<item5;
    m_modelApp->appendRow(listItems);
```

One of the filter in the ProxyModelApp.

```
void ProxyModelApp::setRefLibApp(QString refLibApp){
    if(m_refLibApp != refLibApp)
        m_refLibApp = refLibApp;
    invalidateFilter();
}
```

I would like to know, why after the successful filtering in the function filterAcceptedRows() does not update the view.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to call in you proxy `invalidateFilter()`

Comment: I am calling the InvalidateFilter, whenever i try to filter it. I update the code with this function.

Comment: `m_listApp->setModel(m_proxyApp)`

Comment: Thank you. i understood the problem.

Comment: typo: change `m_lstApp->setModel(m_modelApp);` to `m_lstApp->setModel(m_proxyApp);`

Answer (score 1):

You have the view use `m_modelApp` - the original unfiltered model. You've created `m_proxyApp`, but don't actually use it anywhere.

Comment: I have set the Tableview model as `m_modelApp` and source model of  the `m_proxyApp` as `m_modelApp`

Comment: I assume `m_lstApp` is the view in question. You gave it `m_modelApp` for the model - it knows nothing of `m_proxyApp`

Comment: Thanks Igor. i understood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your table proxy model should be initialized in the following order

```
m_modelApp = new QStandardItemModel();  // Original model
m_proxyApp = new ProxyModelApp();       // Custome proxy model
m_proxyApp->setSourceModel(m_modelApp); // Proxy to original model.
m_lstApp->setModel(m_proxyApp);         // Set the proxy model to the table view
```